# SQL query for calculated column

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, calculated-columns

I have a table that looks like this -

**Table screenshot link** - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pztpq.png

I want to add a new column 'Manufacturer_Updated', such that -

If any particular 'Product' has more than 1 (distinct) 'Manufacturer', then the Manufacturer having highest 'Sales' should be populated in the 'Manufacturer_Updated' column for all rows of that particular 'Product'.

Ex - In the above screenshot, Product - 'TOTAL HAIR CARE NA' has 2 different Manufacturer, so in the 'Manufacturer_Updated' column, 'SEXY HAIR CONCEPTS' should appear for both the rows, as it has the higher sales.

Could someone pls help with this query? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT Manufacturer, Product, Sales, Manufacturer as Manufacturer_Updated FROM
WHERE amt_of_manufacturers > 1
((SELECT Product, max(Sales) as Sales, count(distinct Manufacturer) as amt_of_manufacturers
 FROM your_table
GROUP BY Product) as q1 
left join
(SELECT Manufacturer, Sales, Product
 FROM your_table
) as q2
ON q1.Sales = q2.Sales
   AND q1.Product = q2.Product
   ) as q3
```

In the first query (q1), you're retrieving maximum sales per each product along with amount of manufacturers for a specific product (used later in upper query). In the second one (q2) you just need to retrieve Manufacturer (to transform it later to Manufacturer_Updated), Sales and Product (as join keys). After this you only need to filter out all products with single manufacturer.

Alternatively, if you want to keep those, you can remove *where amt_of_manufacturers > 1* and replace Manufacturer_Updated in the upper query with the following:

```
CASE WHEN
    amt_of_manufacturers <=1 THEN null
    ELSE Manufacturer
    END AS Manufacturer_Updated
```